# show .Net core web API response in highcharts

Tags: javascript, c#, json, highcharts, .net-core

I want to show data in highcharts, API returns json, is any conversion needed to highcharts show data?

code:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<List<Tuple<string, double>>> Get(int id)
{
        using (StockContext stockContext = new StockContext())
        {
            var company = stockContext
                .Companies
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            var info = company
                .Informations
                .ToList()
                .Select(x => new Tuple<string, double>(((long)x.Date.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds).ToString(), x.Close)), x.Close))
                .ToList();
            return new ObjectResult(info);
        }
}
```

sample data:

> [{"item1":"1548201600000","item2":2470.0},
>
> {"item1":"1548115200000","item2":2469.0},
>
> {"item1":"1548028800000","item2":2440.0}]

client-side:

```
fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({
                data: json, // data passed to highcharts but doesn't show anything
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what Highcharts series you want to use, you must provide data in one of three allowed formats:

Array - only `y` - values:

```
data: [0, 5, 3, 5]
```

Array - `x` and `y` values:

```
data: [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 8]
]
```

Object:

```
data: [{
    x: 1,
    y: 9,
    name: "Point2",
    color: "#00FF00"
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 6,
    name: "Point1",
    color: "#FF00FF"
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hpd6kt2z/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data